# Can i know Why this error 'The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.' is shown?

Tags: c#, oledb

```
       public partial class Form1: Form
       {
           OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

       public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();

       }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }  

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
                                Source= Assignment.accdb";
        con.Open();




    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from SignUp where Username = '" + 
                           textBox1.Text + "' and Password= '" + 
                           textBox2.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (count ==1 )
        {
            MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
            menu.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password");
        }

        con.Close();
```

can anyone help me to check my code
How to fix this error 'The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.'

although I have closed the connection

** the message The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.is shown at (con.open(); [private void button1_Click_1])

Comment: You open the connection in both the click event **and** `Form_Load`. This is bad. Remove one of them (likely the `Form_Load` one). It is like you are going up to a door and opening it up. Then going up a few seconds later and trying to open it again. Rightfully the door is saying 'no you can't, I am already open'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend having a read of [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) since it looks like you are storing your passwords in a raw form. This is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: Small tip on asking questions about code that doesn't work: the code should be a [mcve]. *Minimal* means not including empty event handlers which are unrelated to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `this.Close();` closes the Form before that last line executes, or because you're opening the connection in multiple places.

- Remove those lines of code from the `Form1_Load` event and use [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to create the connection right when you need it, which should also cleanup resources (and close connections) for you, no matter what (even if an exception is thrown).
- Also, [always try to parameterize your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/301857).
- Since you're only expecting a single record returned (or nothing if the login is wrong), you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) to simplify things a bit more.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Assignment.accdb"))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from SignUp where Username = @user and Password = @pass";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@user", textBox1.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pass", textBox2.Text));

        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password");
            return;
        }

        MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
        menu.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: another error 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' is shown

Comment: another error 'The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.' is shown

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to open the same connection within two functions:
`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Simply, remove `con.Open();` form `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`